# Javascript One-To-One Object Mapping (Built-in Function?)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, google-apps-script

If I have 2 Arrays (`properties` and `data`):

```
properties = [name, height, weight, zone];

data = [
  ['Luke Skywalker', 123, 112, 'B'],
  ['Jawa', 12, 8, 'B'],
  ['Hutt', 200, 999, 'C']
];
```

and I want to create an array of objects (`statistics`):

```
statistics = [{
    name: 'Luke Skywalker',
    height: 123,
    weight: 112,
    zone: 'B'
  },
  {
    name: 'Jawa',
    height: 12,
    weight: 8,
    zone: 'B'
  }, {
    name: 'Hutt',
    height: 200,
    weight: 999,
    zone: 'C'
  }
];
```

Usually I'd just use map over `data[]`, create a `temp` object, and push it onto `statistics[]`.

But since I know all other entries in `data` have the same dimensions and data types. I also know there's a one-to-one mapping from `properties` to `data`. Is there a built-in function in javascript that outputs an array of objects with a one-to-one mapping? Something like `properties.mapAll(data)` or alike. I'm hoping not to use a library cause I'm doing this on a template `.html` in GAS.

Comment: `properties = [name, height, weight, zone];` Are those really 4 standalone variables? If so, what are they? Or did you mean to use strings?

Comment: To answerers, [tag:google-apps-script] is es3 with cherry picked  es5 functions like map, reduce, etc. `=>` or `...` is not supported.

Comment: @TheMaster note that this is being done in an `.html`. It isn't specified whether this is done as a part of `HtmlTemplate#evaluate` or true client-side code, so arrows and Object.assign may well be available.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the properties are always going to be `name`, `height`, `weight` & `zone` then you can use [Array Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to apply a placeholder name *and* store the value to it within a `map`.

```js
const data = [['Luke Skywalker', 123, 112, 'B'], ['Jawa', 12, 8, 'B'], ['Hutt', 200, 999, 'C']];

const stats = data.map(([name, height, weight, zone]) => ({
  name, 
  height, 
  weight, 
  zone
}))

console.log(stats)
```

*EDIT* Based on the script being on GAS. Here is the same approach but es5.

```js
var data = [['Luke Skywalker', 123, 112, 'B'], ['Jawa', 12, 8, 'B'], ['Hutt', 200, 999, 'C']];

var stats = data.map(function(dataArray) {
  return {
    name: dataArray[0], 
    height: dataArray[1], 
    weight: dataArray[2], 
    zone: dataArray[3]
  }
})

console.log(stats)
```

Comment: this aproach does not use a dynamic approach by taking `properties`.

Comment: Yes like i said above as it is not clear in the OP *If the properties are always going to be name, height, weight & zone then...*

Comment: In an Apps Script `.html` file your can use modern JavaScript, so long as the code being written is being evaluated at "runtime". If the code is being executed during the call to [`HtmlTemplate#evaluate`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-template#evaluate()), then probably the JS syntax needs to be consistent with [JS 1.6 (+ Array filter/map/every/some/reduce methods)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/#basic_javascript_features).

Answer (score 3):

You could map new objects by taking the properties array for building named keys and collect all objects with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

```js
var properties = ['name', 'height', 'weight', 'zone'],
    data = [['Luke Skywalker', 123, 112, 'B'], ['Jawa', 12, 8, 'B'], ['Hutt', 200, 999, 'C']],
    statistics = data.map(a => Object.assign(...properties.map((k, i) => ({ [k]: a[i] }))));

console.log(statistics);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) methods. Iterate over the second array using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method, within that use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method to generate the object and return.

```
let res = data.map(arr => properties.reduce((obj, k, i) => Object.assign(obj, { [k]: arr[i] }), {}));
```

```js
let properties = ['name', 'height', 'weight', 'zone'],

  data = [
    ['Luke Skywalker', 123, 112, 'B'],
    ['Jawa', 12, 8, 'B'],
    ['Hutt', 200, 999, 'C']
  ];

let res = data.map(arr => properties.reduce((obj, k, i) => Object.assign(obj, { [k]: arr[i] }), {}));

console.log(res)
```

or

```
let res = data.map(arr => properties.reduce((obj, k, i) => (obj[k] = arr[i], obj)), {}));
```

```js
let properties = ['name', 'height', 'weight', 'zone'],

  data = [
    ['Luke Skywalker', 123, 112, 'B'],
    ['Jawa', 12, 8, 'B'],
    ['Hutt', 200, 999, 'C']
  ];

let res = data.map(arr => properties.reduce((obj, k, i) => (obj[k] = arr[i], obj), {}));

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array Destructuring` to pull out the values and substitute them for named properties in a returned Object.

```
data.map(([name, height, weight, zone]) => ({name, height, weight, zone}));
```

```js
let data = [['Luke Skywalker', 123, 112, 'B'], ['Jawa', 12, 8, 'B'], ['Hutt', 200, 999, 'C']],

result = data.map(([name, height, weight, zone]) => ({name, height, weight, zone}));


console.log(r);
```

Comment: Is this different in any way from the prior answer from @FrancisLeigh?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/55394677/9337071 Except for your answer having less information?

Comment: @tehhowch Ah! My apologies. I didn't realize that was the same syntactic answer. I'll remove this answer in just a moment :)